# apache 2 script-src permission issue in content security policy

Tags: javascript, apache, xss, content-security-policy, script-src

I need to implement a content security policy for a customer.

Everything works well except for the js scripts. I need to allow external js scripts.

Code in my vhost apache :

```
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff" 
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https:// multiple domains ; img-src 'self' www.googletagmanager.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; script-src *  'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js ; object-src 'self'; form-action 'self' " 
Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin" 
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"      
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
AllowOverride All
```

I added:

```
script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

However, I still get an error message:

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'.
```

What to do ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1. The good and safe option: Rewrite eval statements as explained here https://web.dev/csp/#eval-too
2. The bad and usafe option: Add 'unsafe-eval' to script-src